# Cannot get correct received topic when a message handled by @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)

Tags: spring-kafka

I want to get the topic for a message whose payload cannot be recognized by other KafkaHandler.

```
@KafkaListener(id="group-0", topics={"topic-0","topic-1"})
public class MultiHandler {

@KafkaHandler
public void fooMethod(Foo foo) {}

@KafkaHandler 
public void barMethod(Bar bar) {}

@KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
public void unknownObjectMethod(
  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
  @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) String key,
  Object object) {}
}
```

My question is that if the payload cannot be handler by fooMethod() nor barMethod(), I cannot get the correct topic in unknownObjectMethod(). The value I get for the topic via the above code is the payload itself. I'm confused about why it happens. Please advise how can I get the correct topic in unknownOnjectMethod().

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try making the `object` the first parameter?

Comment: Forget that - I reproduced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug; as a work around, use

```java
@KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
public void def(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
    ...
}
```

I opened an issue for it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1479).